# Yii2 ajax removes custom jquery validatiton

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, yii2

I have an form in which I am using `Yii2 ajax` response to validate unique entities. Now, I have to add some custom jQuery validation and add `Error Message and Error Class using jQuery` but as this field is not validated by Yii2 itself, ajax removes the error message and class which I added by jQuery. May someone help me to stop `Yii2 ajax` to remove this custom validation.

I can't remove Yii2 Ajax because if I do so, it will not validate unique validation on blur.

here is some sample code.

from my _form.php

```
$('#w0').on('beforeSubmit', function (z) {
    $(this).find('input.required').each(function () {
        $(this).on('blur', function () {
            if ($(this).val() == '') {
                $(this).closest('div.form-group').addClass('has-error');
                $(this).closest('div.form-group').find('p').html('This field can not be blank.');
                return false;
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Inside the controller, I have the following lines

```
if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax && $model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
    Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;
    return ActiveForm::validate($model);
}
```

Comment: This is contradictory, your JS event is called when submitted, but inner line has `blur` event, which will not happen. Because you are not moving from one field to another when you are submitting. So its not YII code, but its your JS functions, which is wrong.

Comment: may u please suggest me change? I am not so good an jQuery...

Comment: I posted my suggestion as an answer. here. Try it out and if it does not work then do tell me. I will correct it.

Comment: Sir, its saying "Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list" and when i am  adding ")" it says unexpected...

Comment: I updated my code in the answer. Copy that and try it please.

Comment: It validates but form still submitted. Return false doesn't work.

Comment: I again updated my answer. Please check it.

Answer (score 0):

This is contradictory, your JS event is called when submitted, but the inner line has `blur` event, which will not happen. Because you are not moving from one field to another when you are submitting.

So it's not YII code, but it's your JS functions, which is wrong.

Give the following code a try, it should work:

```
$('#w0').on('beforeSubmit', function (z) {
    $(this).find('input.required').each(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == '') {
            z.preventDefault();
            $(this).closest('div.form-group').addClass('has-error');
            $(this).closest('div.form-group').find('p').html('This field can not be blank.');
        }
    });
});
```